# Python Logging from Library

Tags: python, logging

Hi this is hopefully a basic question. I have a python library with a lot of logger messages such as this:

```
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
log.info("blah")
log.warning("blah")
...
```

Then I have a separate code that imports and runs this library. In that code, I added this, thinking it would cause all logging messages to go to this file:

```
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
fh = logging.FileHandler("/some/file/location/log.txt")
log.addHandler(fh)
```

This does successfully pass all log messages in that script to direct to that file, but the logging messages from the library aren't being passed along. I don't want to specify the file path from within the library, that doesn't make much sense, I want it specified in the code that runs the library. Most of the examples I'm seeing show imports happening with parent/child modules, but what about one module that calls a completely different module? Does my library need to accept a logger as an argument to use, or can I use the logging module to handle this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are creating two instances of the Logger class. Only the instance in your script is being configured to write to the file location.

Each time the 'getLogger' method is called, it provides a reference to the Logger with the specified name. If a Logger with that name doesn't exist, a new one is created. Note that in Python, `__name__` specifies the module name. Since you are calling the library from a script, I'd assume you have two separate modules, hence two different Loggers.

For a quick-and-dirty approach, you can use:

```
import my_library

log = logging.getLogger(my_library.__name__)
fh = logging.FileHandler("/some/file/location/log.txt")
log.addHandler(fh)
```

Where `my_library` is your newly defined library. This will provide the logger which the library instantiated, instead of creating a new one.

Another approach would be to define a module-level function like this:

```
# In your script
import my_library

log_location = "/some/file/location/log.txt"
my_library.set_log_location(log_location)


# In your newly defined library
def set_log_location(path):
    log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    fh = logging.FileHandler("/some/file/location/log.txt")
    log.addHandler(fh)
```

The second approach wouldn't require the user knowing that your library uses the logging module.

Answer (score 1):

In your *application*, e.g. in the `if __name__ == '__main__'` clause, configure the root logger with the handlers you want, using e.g.

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    filename='/some/file/location/log.txt',
                    filemode='w',
                    format='%(asctime)s %(message)s')
```

and then all logging from your application, your libraries and third-party libraries should write log messages to the file. The sources of logged events (application or libraries) don't need to know or care where the events they log end up - that's taken care of by the configuration. If you need more involved configuration than [basicConfig()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig) provides, you can use logging's [dictConfig()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html#logging.config.dictConfig) API to configure logging.